# android.view.InflateException, Error inflating fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-inflate

I want to implement a layout that has a MapView and NavigationView, below is what I tried following [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) tutorial. I am getting this error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragmen` What is wrong?

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ShopsCatalogActivityUsingMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--toolbar-->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">

        </include>

        <!--map-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--map-->
            <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".CustomInfo" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--navigation drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/my_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Line #43 is the one that has the fragment containing the map

Comment: Is that your entire XML file? those need to be wrapped in a drawer layout

Comment: Post the the entire layout file, which line is #43?

Answer (score 0):

In `<fragment`

Change

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

to

`class = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Hope this helps !

Comment: Ok, check if you extend the fragment like this : import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot to add the google maps API key to the manifest file. I added:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```